# What are the reason on why after packaging adobe air application it doesn't work, but running it through command line it works?

Tags: javascript, air, backbone.js, underscore.js

Basically, I have a adobe air project. If I run it through command line (ex, adl application.xml) it works and runs fine. But if I package it and then install it, it doesn't work fine. When I say it works and doesn't work, I mean that when it works everything is displayed correctly and all the templates are displayed and so on, and when I say it doesn't work I mean I see only a few text on the screen but the Underscore templates aren't getting displayed and actually nothing much really gets displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the file url path was wrong.